# Create nested object from list of objects

Tags: javascript, object, nested

Is it possible to parse through this list and create a new nested object for every sensor after "RECORD".

```
{
    "TIMESTAMP": "2022-10-21 13:55:00",
    "RECORD": "0",
    "Sensor1": "1.654",
    "Sensor2": "1.176",
    "Sensor3": "0.706"
}
```

Result:

```
{
    "Sensor1": {
        "TIMESTAMP": "2022-08-21 13:55:00",
        "Value": "1.654"
    },
    "Sensor2": {
        "TIMESTAMP": "2022-08-21 13:55:00",
        "Value": "1.176"
    },
    "Sensor3": {
        "TIMESTAMP": "2022-08-21 13:55:00",
        "Value": "0.706"
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Use `Object.entries(object).forEach()` and check if the key begins with `Sensor`. If so, create the corresponding property in the result.

Comment: Please show what you tried. We'll help you fix it, we won't write it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop through the object keys, ignore the `TIMESTAMP` and `RECORD` keys, and each other key just create its according object with the required values:

```js
const transform = (input) => {
  return Object.keys(input).reduce((accum, inputKey) => {
    if (inputKey === 'TIMESTAMP' || inputKey === 'RECORD') {
      return accum;
    }

    return {
      ...accum,
      [inputKey]: {
        TIMESTAMP: input.TIMESTAMP,
        Value: input[inputKey]
      } 
    };
  }, {})
}

// Example
const exampleObject = {
  "TIMESTAMP": "2022-10-21 13:55:00",
  "RECORD": "0",
  "Sensor1": "1.654",
  "Sensor2": "1.176",
  "Sensor3": "0.706"
};

console.log(transform(exampleObject));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try reducing it with `Object.entries(...).reduce(...);`. Example below:

```js
const input = {
    "TIMESTAMP": "2022-10-21 13:55:00",
    "RECORD": "0",
    "Sensor1": "1.654",
    "Sensor2": "1.176",
    "Sensor3": "0.706"
};

const result = Object.entries(input).reduce((res, [key, val]) => {
  if (!key.startsWith("Sensor")) return res;
  
  res[key] = {
    TIMESTAMP: input.TIMESTAMP,
    Value: val
  };
  
  return res;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```